# Must use exact identifier for APP object with verb SET

Tags: wcf, msmq

I'm following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx) article on allowing WCF to read data from MSMQ but am getting an error with this command

```
appcmd set app "MSMQ/MsmqService" /enabledProtocols:net.msmq
```

MSMQ is the name of my IIS hosted website and MsmqService is the name of the .svc file.

The error I get is

```
ERROR ( message:Must use exact identifer for APP object with verb SET. )
```

Here is what my site looks like in IIS

[image: iis]

Comment: Your Web Site is called MSMQ and not Default Web Site (or similar)?

Comment: Yep = that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sachin, All you are trying to perform by running this command is to set net.msmq in the enabled protocols of the virtual directory. In this specific command the MsmqService is the name of the vDir under your web site MSMQ. If you create a vDir with name MsmqService and execute this command the command will succeed (not the svc file name). And svc files should have the .svc extension for IIS to be able to invoke the appropriate handlers when a request arrives.

Alternatively you can do the same thing in IIS UI following these instructions:

1. inetmgr from run prompt
2. Go to the web site MSMQ
3. Navigate to the vDir MsmqService. Right click  -> Manage application -> "Advanced settings..."
4. Notice a setting named "Enabled Protocols". Type in net.msmq there. Hit OK.

Comment: I don't have a virtual directory called MsmqService.  Please take a look at my edit - I only have what is shown in the image.

Comment: Then you can follow the same UI steps at the site level.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this today, so here's the fix for the "Exact Identifier" error:

Change

`"MSMQ/MsmqService"`

To

`"MSMQ/MsmqService/"`

`appcmd` simply expects a path that includes a slash at the end (exact identifier).