# Azure Release Pipeline IIS deploy

Tags: iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to deploy web api to local IIS servers by embedded in Azure DevOps IIS deploy tools.
For correct deploy app need observe the following rules/order because API URL have format like:
http://host/api/dev/

on web server IIS side:

WEB-SITE-NAME
-virtual directory: api/
--virtual directory: api/dev
---application WEB-SITE-NAME/api/dev

i learned how create this structure on CLI appcmd:

%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe add vdir /app.name:"WEB-API-TEST/" /path:/api /physicalpath:C:\wwwroot-api
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe add vdir /app.name:"WEB-API-TEST/" /path:/api/dev/ /physicalpath:c\wwwroot\WEB-API
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe add app /site.name:"WEB-API-TEST" /path:/api/dev /physicalpath:c:\wwwroot\web-api

these commands correctly work.

I tried used those options in Azure Release Pipeline but have many problems:

1. step for configuration application:
   [image]
   have error:
   [image]
2. In IIS incorrect configurations:

[image: after deploy]

Azure Release Pipeline tasks for IIS VDIR configuration:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @w0nders, how are things going? Is the suggestion in the article shared in my answer helpful to you? Please have a check with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar case that has been solved. Maybe you can try the accepted solution in that ticket to see if it can solve your issue.

- [**Must use exact identifier for APP object with verb SET**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984980/must-use-exact-identifier-for-app-object-with-verb-set)

If the issue still exists, for us to investigate this issue further, please share the complete debug logs of the failed release.